# Manually typing VS setting value in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a bot for kahoot.it that spams the game/lobby with bot players and I'm stuck at trying to enter the lobby number. When I manually type in the number and then execute

```
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click();
```

it works fine, but when I use

```
document.getElementById("inputSession").value = 309510;
```

and then

```
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click();
```

to autofill the box with the number it doesn't work. What is the difference between typing it and setting the value in js?

Comment: Can you explain in more details?

Comment: On the front page of kahoot,it, there's a form for the game number and an "enter" button. if I type in the game number and click the button or use javascript to enter it, it works, but if I use javascript to enter the number, I get a message that says "you need to enter a game number" or something along those lines. Basically, I think that using js to set the value of the form to the game number isn't the same as typing it in for some reason, and I need a sollution

Comment: How did you write the `button` code in html?

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click();

and honestly, I copied and pasted that from another thread but it works as long as I type the game pin in manually(and that's the issue)

Comment: No, i want the code of this `button` in html code?

Comment: im confused, what do you mean how did i write it

Comment: like this `<button></button>`, if you still confused please provide the html code in your question.

Comment: I didn't write it, it's not my site. I'm trying to make a bot that "clicks" the button

Comment: Try to change the type of this `button` and make sure this `button` have a property `type="button"` not `type="submit"`.

Try this:

   `document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].setAttribute("type","button");`
 `document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click();`

Comment: But that's just editing the source html of a website that isn't mine, correct? I need a bot that can take the game number from a website that Im making, and paste it into Kahoot and submit it. Go to "https://kahoot.it/" to see what I'm talking about

Comment: The site is using a framework called AngularJS, which updates its model for what the input is doing with a method called `ng-change` that does not update when the input value is set through javascript. You can check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27536772/ngchange-doesnt-work-when-the-model-is-changed-programmatically) for more information, or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17626604/how-to-trigger-ng-change-in-directive-test-in-angularjs). I'm sure its possible to spoof but it would take more knowledge of angular's interiors than I have.

Comment: Finally, thank you. I think I'm gonna go a different route and simulate actual typing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site is using a framework called AngularJS, which updates its model for what the input is doing with a method called ng-change that does not update when the input value is set through javascript. You can check out this SO question for more information, or this one. I'm sure its possible to spoof but it would take more knowledge of angular's interiors than I have. – @Matt O'Tousa

Answer (score 0):

"What is the difference between typing it and setting the value in js?"

You might be getting a string if you type it in a input box. On the other hand, setting the value would assign a number.

Comment: nope, I put it in quotes and I still got the "You need to enter a game pin before you can play", It still filled the form though. I copied it and pasted it right back and then entered it and it worked fine; very weird...