# How to get browser to detect change in value of input field?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently creating a Google Chrome Extension with Javascript and I'm attempting to autofill a credit card input field whenever I load the page. I tried selecting the JS path and setting the value like this:

```
cardNumber = document.querySelector("#cardNumber-input")
cardNumber.value = "1111 1111 1111 1111"
```

This does show up in the input field, however the input isn't detected by the browser unless I manually amend one of the digits. I did some googling and this probably has to do with the fact that the input field is written in AngularJS (I'm not completely sure but this is how the element looks like when inspect it)

```
<input _ngcontent-ng-cli-universal-c30="" type="text" name="cardNumber" id="cardNumber-input" autocomplete="cc-number" required="" maxlength="23" ccnumber="" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched">
```

**To give some context, "ng-invalid" changes to "ng-valid" in the elements when I type the digits manually.** I did try doing this with Selenium in python with the sendKeys() function and it worked fine. Is there any other way to set the value of an input field or is there any code I need to write to allow the input field to actually detect the value in it? Thanks in advance.

P.S. This is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50033445/manually-typing-vs-setting-value-in-js) to someone else that asked a similar question to me. Someone mentioned about the site using "AngularJS, which updates its model for what the input is doing with a method called ng-change that does not update when the input value is set through javascript". However there was no answer to the question.

Comment: have you tried to `cardNumber.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('change'))` after, or to dispatch an `input` event?

Comment: cardNumber.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('change')) only returns true in the chrome console. The input field still doesn't detect the input.

Comment: @AndreaGiammarchi Dispatching an input event worked for me! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

cardNumber.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('change')) to dispatch an input event works great.